# How to redirect user after logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a front end built in Angular. I have the following code in `app.js` for when user clicks logout.

```
  .when('/logout', {
    templateUrl: 'mysite/views/logout.html',
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    }
  })
```

logout.js contains

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp')
  .controller('LogoutCtrl', function ($scope, $location, djangoAuth) {
    djangoAuth.logout();
  });
```

`logout.html` simply contains this:

```
<div id="logout_view" ng-controller="LogoutCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-info">You have logged out.</div>
</div>
```

All of this works fine, however, when user clicks `/logout` I don't want to show a the `logout.html` page which simply shows `You have logged out` rather I want to redirect the user to my `main.html` page. However, when I change the `templateUrl` to go to `mysite/views/main.html` then the `LogoutCtrl` isn't being called and the user isn't really being logged out.

**Question**

Is there a way I can redirect the user to `main.html` after he logs out successfully (meaning the logic in `logout.js` gets executed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace with following: (It will execute logout logic and will show your page)

```
.when('/logout', {
    templateUrl: 'mysite/views/main.html',
    controller: LogoutCtrl,
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    }
  })
```

Comment: have youd include the js file in your index.html, it will make sure your controller is registered before its being used?